# Numba Parallize a ''for'' in a function called from lambda function (gradient evaluation)

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, numba, parfor

I am quite new to Python and I writing to ask for some help!

I want to parallelize the ''for'' in the following function

```
def gfunc(Func,z,V,x):
    xVz=x+V@z
    f1=Func(xVz)
    W=zeros_like(V)
    m=V.shape[1]
    h=np.finfo(x.dtype).eps ** (1./2)*(1+norm(f1))
    for i in xrange(m):
        W[:,i]=(Func(xVz+h*V[:,i])-f1)/h
    f=0.5*norm(f1)**2
    g=W.transpose()@f1
    return f,g
```

where (z, V, x are numpy arrays) and after using the result of this function as

```
gf= lambda z: gfunc(Func,z,V,x)[0]
gr= lambda z: gfunc(Func,z,V,x)[1]
```

to be used in scipy's l_bfgs_b. Which is the best way to do this? I tryed something using numba as follows

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def par_diff(Func, xVz, h, f1, V):
    W=zeros_like(V)
    m=V.shape[1]
    for i in prange(m):
        W[:,i]=(Func(xVz+h*V[:,i])-f1)/h
        return W



def gfunc(Func,z,V,x):
    xVz=x+V@z
    f1=Func(xVz)
    h=np.finfo(x.dtype).eps ** (1./2)*(1+norm(f1))
    W=par_diff(Func,xVz,h,f1,V)
    end=time.time()
    print(end-start)
    f=0.5*norm(f1)**2
    g=W.transpose()@f1
    return f,g
```

but I receive the following error

```
raise value.with_traceback(tb)

TypingError: non-precise type pyobject
[1] During: typing of argument at
```

Any help is very much appreciated!
Best
Stefano

Edit: Following you find a MRE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root
from numpy import cosh, zeros_like, mgrid, zeros
from scipy import optimize
from numpy import asarray 
from scipy.linalg import norm
from scipy._lib.six import callable, exec_, xrange
from numba import njit, prange
import numba
# parameters
nx, ny = 75, 75
hx, hy = 1./(nx-1), 1./(ny-1)

P_left, P_right = 0, 0
P_top, P_bottom = 1, 0

def residual(P):
   d2x = zeros_like(P)
   d2y = zeros_like(P)

   d2x[1:-1] = (P[2:]   - 2*P[1:-1] + P[:-2]) / hx/hx
   d2x[0]    = (P[1]    - 2*P[0]    + P_left)/hx/hx
   d2x[-1]   = (P_right - 2*P[-1]   + P[-2])/hx/hx

   d2y[:,1:-1] = (P[:,2:] - 2*P[:,1:-1] + P[:,:-2])/hy/hy
   d2y[:,0]    = (P[:,1]  - 2*P[:,0]    + P_bottom)/hy/hy
   d2y[:,-1]   = (P_top   - 2*P[:,-1]   + P[:,-2])/hy/hy

   return d2x + d2y - 2*cosh(P).mean()**2
### Functions

def _as_inexact(x):
    """Return `x` as an array, of either floats or complex floats"""
    x = asarray(x)
    if not np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.inexact):
        return asarray(x, dtype=np.float_)
    return x


def _array_like(x, x0):
    """Return ndarray `x` as same array subclass and shape as `x0`"""
    x = np.reshape(x, np.shape(x0))
    wrap = getattr(x0, '__array_wrap__', x.__array_wrap__)
    return wrap(x)

## Functions to be parallelized

### Decomment from here to #1####1 to see working code
'''
def gfunc(Func,z,V,x):
    xVz=x+V@z
    f1=Func(xVz)
    W=zeros_like(V)
    m=V.shape[1]
    #h=numdiffp(x0Vz.flatten(),f1)
    h=np.finfo(x.dtype).eps ** (1./2)*(1+norm(f1))
    #start=time.time()
    for i in xrange(m):
        W[:,i]=(Func(xVz+h*V[:,i])-f1)/h
    #end=time.time()
    #print(end-start)
    f=0.5*norm(f1)**2
    g=W.transpose()@f1
    return f,g      

#1####1
'''
## Comment From here to #2####2 to see working code 
@njit(parallel=True)
def par_diff(Func, xVz, h, f1, V):
    W=zeros_like(V)
    m=V.shape[1]
    for i in prange(m):
        W[:,i]=(Func(xVz+h*V[:,i])-f1)/h
        return W



def gfunc(Func,z,V,x):
    xVz=x+V@z
    f1=Func(xVz)
    h=np.finfo(x.dtype).eps ** (1./2)*(1+norm(f1))
    W=par_diff(Func,xVz,h,f1,V)
    end=time.time()
    print(end-start)
    f=0.5*norm(f1)**2
    g=W.transpose()@f1
    return f,g      
#2####2

# Using the machinery

guess = np.ones((nx, ny), float)
x0 = _as_inexact(guess)

Func = lambda z: _as_inexact(residual(_array_like(z, x0))).flatten()
x = x0.flatten()

ndim=x.shape[0]

V=np.random.rand(ndim,5)


gf= lambda z: gfunc(Func,z,V,x)[0]
gr= lambda z: gfunc(Func,z,V,x)[1]


result =optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(gf, np.zeros(5), fprime=gr, m=7, 
                                       factr= 1E-5, 
                                       pgtol= 1E-3)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example, include input parameters for `par_diff`  that trigger the error.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys first of all thank you very much for your interest! I added a MRE in the original post! Best, Stefano

Comment: That is a reproducible example, but not really a *minimal* one.  Isolate the problem by removing code until the error disappears.